# Groovy - get JAVA_HOME from program

Tags: groovy, gradle

I need to obtain JAVA_HOME property from Groovy (Gradle), does anyone know how to achieve this? Only way I can think of is somehow executing this from cmd line via Exec.

Thanks
(I'm running Windows btw :))

Comment: Gradle should work with the jdk it finds in your classpath. If you set your JAVA_HOME variable properly, then Gradle will use it.

Comment: Yes, It will :). But I need this path for generation of some specific configuration files for other systems in my build. Question is not directly associated with running gradle.

Comment: Great! the answer provided by @Will P should do the trick, then!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
System.properties.find { it.key == "java.home" }
```

Comment: Ok, thx guys. Still, java.home points to JRE according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html. Since I need path to JDK directory %JAVA_HOME%, I will probably have to get it via exec plugin.

Comment: What's the value of your JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: @MatthewLowe try `System.env.'JAVA_HOME'`

Comment: Actually I found that: `System.properties.'java.home'`, points to the JRE installed _under_ the JDK that Gradle was/is using on my PC.  Looks like Gradle/Groovy's running JVM instance.  Not the value of the system JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

A gotcha that bit me. Remember to use curly braces inside a gstring.

`println "inside a gstring, java.home=$System.properties.'java.home' will be problematic`

//dumps all system properties

but

`println "inside a gstring, java.home=${System.properties.'java.home'} will be fine`

`Result: inside a gstring, java.home=C:\FAST\JDK64\1.7.0.79\jre will be fine`